# Creating a PM calendar event from Google Form Submit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api, google-forms

Good afternoon! This my first time posting and let me acknowledge that I am a professional educator but an amateur at script writing. I used some guidance from this site to write a script that creates a calendar event each time a form is submitted. The form is for "early releases" for teams from our school so I made a dummy sheet as an example here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b-8FWWppyNqfycMmc4E3TLT4Fl7W-TJqoG3Zy6XSCkQ/edit?usp=sharing

. The calendar events then go to an activity calendar that is shared with teachers. The issue I am having is the time's submitted always default to am but most are pm. I tried to fix it myself but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated!

```
function createCalEvent(e) {
  Logger.log(e);
  // this will return something like this :
  /*
  {values=[11/9/2014 22:30:00, serge, test descr, 11/7/2014, Before school | 7:30], 
  namedValues={Your Full Name=[serge], Work to Make Up=[test descr], Date You Will Make Up Assignment=[11/7/2014], 
  Makeup Time=[Before school | 7:30], Timestamp=[11/9/2014 22:30:00]}, range=Range, source=Spreadsheet, authMode=FULL}
  */
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("c_2d83fb444341942e6e44b791b97bd5db57611ab24aebfc16ed17a8b4a5ca0ad2@group.calendar.google.com");// replace with the right calendar ID, this one is for test (and is public)
  var name = e.namedValues["Coach/Advisor Name"][0];
  var team = e.namedValues["Team/Club/Organization"][0];
  var descr = e.namedValues["Name of Event"][0];
  var location = e.namedValues["Location to be released to"][0];
  var date = e.namedValues["Date of Event"][0].split('/');
  var time = e.namedValues["Time for Release"][0].split(':');
  var hrs = time[0];
  var mnts = time[1];
  Logger.log(name+' '+descr+' '+date[1]+' '+time[1]); // this will return  serge test descr 11,7,2014  7,30
  var startTime = new Date(date[2],date[0]-1,date[1]);
        var hours = hrs.toString();
        var minutes = mnts.toString();
  startTime.setHours(hours,minutes,0,0);
  endTime = new Date(startTime.getTime()+900000); //assuming event is 1 hour long
  Logger.log('start='+startTime+'  end='+endTime);
  cal.createEvent('Early Release for '+team, startTime, endTime, {'description':descr+' submitted by '+name+ '(please release to '+location+')'});
   cal.addEmailReminder(15);
   cal.addPopupReminder(15);
}
```

I tried to create an "if" statement where if hours < 4, then +12 but it ended up moving the events to the wrong days and still not the right time. With the code as it is now, I get the right day, and hour, it's just the events are set to 2 or 3 am instead of pm.

Comment: It's a little hard to know exactly what's going on without seeing some sample data at least. I understand you can't share the original sheet, but a sample sheet that mimics what issue you are experiencing would be helpful. If the times are written in the spreadsheet with the AM/PM you can concatenate the full date time to a string via template literals and then do something like: new Date(`${date} ${hours}:${minutes} PM`)

Comment: `so I can't share the sheet with you because of privacy issues with the minors named` No one expects any user to share private information. Just use dummy information .

Comment: Miguel, I made a copy and eliminated personal information https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b-8FWWppyNqfycMmc4E3TLT4Fl7W-TJqoG3Zy6XSCkQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`The issue I am having is the time's submitted always default to am but most are pm.`

**The issue**

The "problem" is that time is *entered* in the Form as a 24 hour clock but is recorded in the Sheet/Event Object as a 12 clock.

| Form | Sheet |
| --- | --- |
| 08:30 | "8:30:00 AM" |
| 15:30 | "3:30:00 PM" |

In the sheet, the meridian marker is at the end of the time ("AM" or "PM"). This means that the hour value will always fall between 1 and 12 **regardless of whether the Release Time is "AM" or "PM"**.

This line: `var time = e.namedValues["Time for Release"][0].split(':');` captures the split for hours and minutes but doesn't return the meridian marker.

**Solution**

1. Capture the meridian marker:
   `var timeMarker = e.namedValues["Release time"][0].slice(-2)`
2. Evaluate whether the marker = "PM"

- if yes, add 12
- if no, use the raw hours

**For example:**

- "8:30:00 AM" will return hours = 8
- "3:30:00 PM" will return hours = 15 `(12+3)`

This answer uses `slice(-2)` to extract the marker (last 2 characters in the time string) and then an `IF` statement to test for "PM", but there are *many* ways of doing this. The method in this answer should be regarded as just one approach.

---

```
function releaseHours(e) {

  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) // DEBUG

  // get the Release time
  var time = e.namedValues["Release time"][0].split(':');
  // get the time marker (AM or PM)
  var timeMarker = e.namedValues["Release time"][0].slice(-2)
  Logger.log("DEBUG: RAW DATA: Time = "+time+", time marker = "+timeMarker)

  if (timeMarker === "PM"){
    var hrs = parseInt(time[0])+12
  }
  else{
    var hrs = parseInt(time[0])
  }
  Logger.log("DEBUG: Adjusted hours = "+hrs)
}
```

---

Comment: I've added that into the code, now we'll wait to see if it works. Thanks for the help!